# Protractor: wait for an element and then perform action

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I have written below code to check for locator type and based on whether element is visible or not, I am returning element. I am receiving error on call type(locatorType, value,text) method with appropriate values.

```
this.type = function(locatorType,value,text){
        this.getElement(locatorType,value).sendKeys(text)
    };

this.getElement = function(locatorType,value){
        if(locatorType=='model'){
            console.log(locatorType)
            console.log(value)
            return this.waiterFunc(element(by.model(value)));
        }
        else if(locatorType=='xPath'){
            return this.waiterFunc(element(by.xPath(value)));
        }

        else if(locatorType=='buttonText'){
            return this.waiterFunc(element(by.buttonText(value)));
        }
    };

this.waiterFunc = function(element){
        console.log('In waiterfunc')
        //console.log(element.getText())
        browser.wait(function() {           
            return this.isVisible(element).then(function(){
                return element;
            })
        })
    };

this.isVisible = function(element){
        return EC.visibilityOf(element);
    };
```

Below is the error being received:
[image]

WebDriver is not able to find the element and perform the actions on it. Please suggest where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the waiting function with the element return:

```
this.getElement = function(locatorType, value) {
    var elm;

    if (locatorType == 'model') {
        elm = element(by.model(value));
        this.waiterFunc(elm);
    }
    else if (locatorType == 'xPath') {
        elm = element(by.xpath(value));  // also renamed xPath -> xpath
        this.waiterFunc(elm); 
    }

    else if (locatorType == 'buttonText') {
        elm = element(by.buttonText(value));
        this.waiterFunc(elm);
    }
    return elm;
};
```

In this case the `waiterFunc` would become simpler:

```
this.waiterFunc = function(element){
    browser.wait(this.isVisible(element));
};
```

Comment: It still fails with error: Failures:
Failed: this.getElement(...).sendKeys is not a function

Comment: And while running code I can see it is not waiting for element to load.